# Send Notification via Firebase to everyone in a topic but the sender

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

How can I send a notification to everyone who is subscribed for a topic but the message sender? I'm sorry the JS code is really lame I promise I will improve it, this code sends the push notification to everyone who is currently subscribed including the message sender, I just need to stop sending for the sender, thanks

```js
let functions = require('firebase-functions');
var admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)

exports.newMessage = functions.database.ref('groups/{groupId}/messages/{messageId}')
 .onWrite(event => {
  const message = event.data.val()
  const groupId = event.params.groupId

  sendNotification(message, groupId)
 })


 function sendNotification(message, groupdIdTopic) {
  let title = message.placeName
  let subtitle = message.content

  let payload = {
   notification: {
    title: title,
    body: subtitle,
    sound: 'default',
    badge: '1',
    mutable_content: 'true'
   },
   data : {
         placeId : groupdIdTopic,
         userSenderId : message.senderId
      }
  }

  var options = {
       priority: "high",
       timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24,
       mutable_content : true,
       content_available : true,
       category : 'reminder'
     }


  admin.messaging().sendToTopic(groupdIdTopic, payload, options)
 }
```

Comment: Is the client app web or mobile (Android/iOS)?

Comment: iOS, you marked it as duplicate, so please send me the original one

Answer (score 0):

Messages are sent to all devices subscribed to the topic.  There is no way to exclude a device from a topic, unless it unsubscribes itself before the message is sent.

Seems like you want to include some value in the message that the sender can use to identify that the message came from itself, then use that to choose to ignore the entire message.

Aside, your function doesn't return a promise indicating when the message it sent.  It's entirely possible that the message will never be sent because Cloud Functions may clean it up before the message is sent.